# Thread.Sleep() vs. Monitor.Wait/Monitor.Pulse

Tags: .net, multithreading

I have a windows service that can host one or more background threads.  Each background thread starts a polling loop to check for work.  I've been using the following pattern to implement the loop:

```
new Thread(DoWork).Start();

private void DoWork()
{
    while(keepRunning)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to find an alternative that will consume less CPU.  I've been able to achieve a polling loop using a Timer with a recursive method:

```
var timer = new Timer(WakeUp, null, Timeout.Infinite, 1000)
timer.Change(0, 1000);

private void WakeUp(object state)
{
    lock (locker)
        Monitor.Pulse(locker);
}

private void DoWork()
{
    lock (locker)
    {
        if (!keepRunning) return;
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
        Monitor.Wait(locker);
        DoWork();
    }
}
```

Are there any advantages to using one pattern over the other?  Is there a better pattern for setting up a polling loop in a background thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to find an alternative that will consume less CPU.

Do you have any evidence that it's actually consuming a significant amount of CPU at the moment? Unless you're got a *lot* of threads which are waking up at similar times and contending, I'd expect `Thread.Sleep` to be reasonably efficient.

Your recursive `DoWork` method is far *worse* - unless it's tail-call optimized, you'll eventually blow up with a stack overflow. Why aren't you at least looping? Why don't you just do the actual work in the timer thread to start with?

If you really want one thread per task, doing some work once per second, then your first code is okay (although you'll want to make sure you "see" any new values of `keepRunning` if it's just a field - consider using `Interlocked`). Ideally though, you shouldn't have those threads at all - just have appropriate timers to *schedule* the work once per second, and let the thread pool handle it.

Comment: I have a single Windows Service that launches multiple threads.   The number of threads is controlled via configuration.  All threads loop in the background using while(true) ... Thread.Sleep(). There is no shared data between threads.  keepRunning is being implemented using a CancellationToken controlled by the main thread and passed into each background thread. The recursive example was an attempt to periodically wake up each background thread using a single timer.  I see now why this is a bad idea.  My main concern was that using Thread.Sleep was an anti-pattern.